# Clustering algorithm for gps data

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, dbscan

I have a data set consisting of gps coordinates for points over a particular city (let's take San Francisco for example). I want to cluster the coordinates into groups such as in the image:

[image]

Should I use k-means or DBSCAN or some other clustering algorithm? Should I find the clusters first and then find the border points to draw the boundaries?